# examine site search with umbraco 4.7 and medium trust

Tags: search, umbraco, medium-trust

I'm trying to use umbraco examine for the site search. It works fine on the development machine, however, on the shared host, the indexes are not being built. the shared host uses medium trust.
I've tried doing the steps mentioned here: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/medium-trust-with-umbraco-45plus, but I cannot use the first step:

```
<trust level="Medium" originUrl=".*" />
```

It gives this error:

```
This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using <location allowOverride="false"> from an inherited configuration file.
```

**Can I use umbraco examine in a medium trust shared hosting environment?**

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a:

requirePermission="false"

to the config section declarations:

```
<section name="Examine" type="Examine.Config.ExamineSettings, Examine" requirePermission="false"/>   
<section name="ExamineLuceneIndexSets" type="Examine.LuceneEngine.Config.IndexSets, Examine" requirePermission="false" />
```